# Back to previous activity without refresh it

Tags: android, android-fragments

i know some people asked the question, but no answers helped me, and i'm new on android :)

So i have a FragmentActivity and Fragments in it.

I my FragmentActivity , i have a function that any fragment can call : OpenHowToActivity().

```
public void OpenHowToActivity(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this,HowTo.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

So in this Activity HowTo i tried many things but none worked.

I want that when i press back button on this activity (howto activity), i go back to my FragmentActivity without reloading it : if i was on the fragment 3 i must come back on fragment 3 and do not reload all datas that i load in the onCreate() in FragmentActivity (i'm loading some sounds for exemple);

Actually, if i do it like it is, i reload all my FragmentActivity (onCreate() etc), and it's a bit long.

Thanks for your help, as usual :)

Comment: When going back to the activity only `onResume` will run. If your `onCreate` is being run then you're doing something else wrong. Was the orientation changed in between?

Comment: No changes : i open the howtoActivity via the menu, the orientation is still the same, my phone doesn't move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to myself and then go to hang myself ...

I ticked the option "Do not keep activities" in "Advanced parameters" so each time i was launching a new activity the caller activity was finished and there was my problem !

Comment: 'ere ya go. Told ya you were doing something weird :) . Glad you figured it out.